# Find optgroup by label inside a select using jquery

Tags: jquery

Please see the code below:

```
var mySelect = $("#mySelect");
//I want to check if optgroup with label myLabel exists inside this select
if(mySelect.find("optgroup[label='myLabel']").html() == null)){
   ///// code
}
```

The `find()` syntax is probably wrong. Please help me find the correct syntax

Comment: It will find `<optgroup label="myLabel">`, is that what you want?

Comment: `if(mySelect.find("optgroup[label='myLabel']").length > 0)`?

Comment: can you share the html you are searching for?

Comment: The standard way of checking whether a selector selected something is to check the `.length` property. However, looks like your code does work (http://jsfiddle.net/4Lkjb/) **after** fixing the syntax error (extra closing `)` in your if statement).

Comment: sry. My code is working already. I was not adding options inside optgroups so even the optgroups were not visible inside select. Thanks for help, learnt something new

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your looking for this solution.

```
$('#main_category').on('change', function() {
  var subCat = document.querySelector('optgroup[label="'+ this.value +'"]');
  $(subCat).removeClass('d-none');
});
```